# trying to list all projects from devops from my asmx webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, devops, restsharp

I'm trying to use azure devops API from my web service.  I made the code using console app and everything works fine, so it does in PowerShell using invoke-restmethod, but when I paste the exact working code in my web service project, I get unable to connect to the server.

Am I missing something in my web.config or something?

```
public class DevOps : System.Web.Services.WebService

{
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetAllProjects()
    {
        var rep = new UseDevOps();
        return rep.GetProjects();
    }
}
    public string GetProjects()
    {
        string url = "https://dev.azure.com/(my organisation)/_apis/";
        string token = "here is my token";
        ModelJson Obj = new ModelJson();                
        var client = new RestSharp.RestClient(url);

        var request = new RestRequest("Projects", Method.GET);
        request.AddParameter("Authorization", "Basic " + token, ParameterType.HttpHeader);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        if(!(response.ErrorMessage is null))
        {
            Obj.Content = response.ErrorMessage.ToString();
            Obj.ExitCode = 1;
            Obj.ExitMessage = response.ErrorMessage.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Obj.Content = response.Content;
            Obj.ExitCode = 0;
            Obj.ExitMessage = string.Empty;
        }
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Obj);
    }
```

Comment: _"unable to connect to the server"_ - then there's probably a firewall blocking outgoing requests for that user or machine. Check with your systems administrator.

Comment: But when i use the same code in a console application project it work...  same machine dame code....

Comment: i think i need to set my web client, since its used as proxy in a webmethod to use whatever protocol or something in the web.config ?